# Estimators: Square in expected value VS Variance?

Tags: expectation, estimation, variance

I've spent so much time trying to proof to myself these are equivalent, but it's not working out.

Given some $X = u + Y$,

where $Y \sim N(0,1)$.

I have some estimator $Z = 2x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^N x_i^2 + 2x_{N+1}$

$Var[z] = E[Z^2] = E[(2x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^N x_i^2 + 2x_{N+1})^2] = 4 + N + 4 = N + 8$

because the variance is distributed.

$ Var[2x_0] + Var[\sum_{i=0}^N x_i^2] + Var[2x_{N+1}] $

However, when I try to distribute the terms as a polynomial instead, I definitely don't get that answer. I know I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

$Var[z] = E[Z^2] = E[(2x_0 + \sum_{i=0}^N x_i^2 + 2x_{N+1})^2] = E[4x_0^2 + 2x_0\sum_{i=0}^N x_i^2+...+2x_N\sum_{i=0}^N x_i^2+4x_{N+1}^2]$

Comment: Note: it may just be my understanding of variance is flawed.

Comment: What do you mean by "because the variance is distributed"? I think this is where you have made an error. Variance does *not* distribute over sums, and moreover your sum is squared, so you will have to multiply it out as you did at the bottom.

Comment: The calculation of the variance in line 5 is not correct. And the mean of $Z$ is not zero if u is different from zero.

Comment: I looked at the solution of a similar problem and the only way I could understand the progression was through taking the square and disregarding it by using the variance. (Also, assumed i.i.d.)

Comment: @AlexG Observe even if x_i are i.i.d., x_0 appears in the first and the second terms of the estimator (you started the sum at i =0).

Comment: There may be inconsistencies because I modified the estimator and summation so it wasn't a straight rip of the problem.

Comment: I also neglected to add $ - E[Z]^2$ at the end of the variance.

Comment: I gave an answer below where you can see how the variance can be computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations of the variance are not correct.

You can write $X\sim N(u,1)$. And $X^2 = u^2 + Y^2 + 2uY$.
Thus,
$$E[X] = u$$
and
$$E[X^2] = u^2+1,$$
this is just the second moment of $X$.

Then the variance of $Z$ is defined as
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}[Z] &= E[ (Z - E[Z])^2 ]\\
&= E[Z^2] - (E[Z])^2
\end{aligned}

Note that
$$
E[Z] = 4u + (N+1)(u^2+1).
$$

Comment: Why is $E[X^2] = u^2 + 1$?
$+1$ comes from the $Y^2$ term?

Comment: Yes, +1 is from the $Y^2$. Observe that $Var[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$.

Comment: This is where part of my confusion is coming from, I think.

Comment: I thought the second moment *was* the variance -- if it's zero mean.

Comment: Yes, your $X$ has a mean equal to $u$; Thus, the variance and the second moments are not equal. Same holds in turn for $Z$.

Comment: I'll go back and rework the problem, see if I was making some of these mistakes. Thanks!